# CRUD orderBy with relationship

Tags: laravel-backpack

I'm having difficulty ordering the CRUD rows by a related value. In my main case I want to order jobs by the weight of their associated status

```
Job (table)->status_id ---> Status (table)->weight
```

I've got belongsTo and hasMany relationships setup correctly and add / edit etc, works well, I just can't figure out how to set the `$this->crud->orderBy()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's no different than sorting any Laravel model by its relation. And I think the standard way is to use [Laravel's eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) for that:

```
$this->crud->query = $this->crud->query->with(['status' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('weight', 'desc');
}])->get();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This worked for me, but in my case I had to remove the `->get()`  to avoid `Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 passed in /home/vagrant/sites/bookit-nexxus/vendor/backpack/crud/src/PanelTraits/Read.php on line 102 and at least 1 expected`